# Improving the quality of YD1875 audio amplifier IC

Tags: amplifier, sound

I had some 1875 amplifier ICs laying around from my old VCD player. I decided to give them a shot, but no matter what LM1875 circuit I slapped together, it didn't work.

After much frustration I found out that my ICs are YD1875s which are apparently a bit different from LM1875s. I downloaded the YD1875 datasheet and put a circuit together and voilà, it works, but the sound quality is not what it used to be on the VCD. The lows and especially the high frequencies are cut, more noticable in higher volumes. Is there a way to improve the quality?

Schematic from the datasheet:

[image]

Comment: I've never used this IC, but one thing springs to mind, Have you carefully checked (with a meter if possible) the components in the feedback loop R6, R5 and C3. If any of them are not as specified it could cause your problem or there could even be a misprint. Is there any frequency response specification for that particular circuit? Have you tried simulating it?

Comment: @PeterJennings no unfortunately the datasheet is only 4 pages and no expected frequency response is specified, even if it did I wouldn't have a oscilloscope to measure it, hard to diagnose unknown chips like these... yea my components are as specified, can't measure the capacitor but it must be alright. datasheet https://datasheetspdf.com/mobile/853288/WuxiYoudaelectronics/YD1875/1

Comment: @PeterJennings swapped c4 and c7 and it eliminated all the clippings, c4 was faulty and c7 was probably too low, works fine with 660uf now. is there a way to increase volume as the circuit draws around 200mA max @ 24v, I think it could do much louder, also can I fine tune the treble and bass somehow? it used to push much deeper bass in the old circuit.

Comment: As I said, I'm not familiar with this type of IC, so I'm afraid I can't answer that part of your question. I must leave it to others.

Comment: @PeterJennings thanks for your kind help I appreciate it! :)